# Learning Swift & Xcode - @IBAction func reset for display if UITextField is empty

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode8

Disclaimer: I am teaching myself Swift & Xcode so my question is rather simple.

I'm building a simple application to get started, which has a text field connected to a String output.

The lesson I'm on currently has an excerpt which reads:

"The reset method simply needs to clear out the text of both the nameField and the lyricsView—you can do this by setting each of their text properties to an empty string."

I understand this probably involves an if statement, but I think the explanation on this is rather poor.

Here's the viewcontroller:

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var nameField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var lyricsView: UITextView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func reset(_ sender: Any) {
}

@IBAction func displayLyrics(_ sender: Any) {
}
```

}

Can someone explain what they mean by setting the properties of nameField and lyricsView to an empty string in order to reset?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clear those fields I'd use:

```
@IBAction func reset(_ sender: Any) {
    nameField?.text = ""
    lyricsView?.text = ""
}
```

The question mark will safely execute the code even if, for some reasons, those fields are not loaded yet, or have been freed or removed.

Comment: That's awesome.  I'm just starting to learn how awesome the ? and ! operators are.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to clear the text of a textField or a textView, just set the `text` property to an empty string. As your lesson hint:

> The reset method simply needs to clear out the text of both the
>   nameField and the lyricsView—you can do this by setting each of their
>   text properties to an empty string.

The reset method should like this:

```
@IBAction func reset(_ sender: Any) {
    nameField.text = ""
    lyricsView.text = ""
}
```

Comment: I have zero experience in programming so I'm sure some of my questions are obvious.

Answer (score 0):

ADD this to reset method to remove the content:-

```
 nameField.text = ""
 lyricsView.text = ""
```

Comment: Thanks, Anuraj.  I am new to this so lots of ELI5 moments going on :)

Answer (score 0):

When you enter something into `nameField` something shows up in your `lyricsView`. So, there should be a way to clear what you've entered (and what is displayed). Hence, the reset function (I guess it's bound to a button).

Once you hit reset the text in `nameField` and `lyricsView` should disappear. You can do this by assigning both to something called *an empty string*, which is just two double-quotes:

```
let anEmptyString = ""
```

You'd need to assign the `""` to the `nameField` and `lyricsView` text property.